# Why does this scrolling script not smooth scroll but jump to the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code which is supposed to smooth scroll to an anchor on the page whenever an  tag is clicked. However, this code does not scroll smoothly but instead jumps to the div.

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure? as its working perfectly fine for me, check this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/fevgLwwk)

Comment: Yes. Is there anything that could be preventing this from working on my end?

Comment: Have you included the JQ library? checked your browser console? other than that we can't guess more.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I just found it it is because I set `position: fixed` and `overflow: hidden` to body  + html. I removed `position: fixed` and set `overflow: hidden` so it only affects the body.

Comment: i.e. why here at **SO** before asking any question one need to at least create a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets) or [**create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to someone to provide more accurate help.